# Trouble analyzing the jmeter output

Tags: load, jmeter, performance-testing

I am new to jmeter and i have run a request and the response i got looks like below:

1435982829092,373,Review?ProductID=1245572,200,OK,jp@gc - Stepping Thread Group 1-1,text,true,294,32,32,373
1435982829131,375,Review?ProductID=1245572,200,OK,jp@gc - Stepping Thread Group 1-1,text,true,294,32,32,375
1435982829132,383,Review?ProductID=1245572,200,OK,jp@gc - Stepping Thread Group 1-1,text,true,294,32,32,382
1435982829132,383,Review?ProductID=1245572,200,OK,jp@gc - Stepping Thread Group 1-1,text,true,294,32,32,383
1435982829132,383,Review?ProductID=1245572,200,OK,jp@gc - Stepping Thread Group 1-1,text,true,294,32,32,383
1435982829131,384,Review?ProductID=1245572,200,OK,jp@gc - Stepping Thread Group 1-2,text,true,294,32,32,384
1435982829132,384,Review?ProductID=1245572,200,OK,jp@gc - Stepping Thread Group 1-2,text,true,294,32,32,384
1435982829132,432,Review?ProductID=1245572,200,OK,jp@gc - Stepping Thread Group 1-2,text,true,294,32,32,432
1435982829172,392,Review?ProductID=1245572,200,OK,jp@gc - Stepping Thread Group 1-27,text,true,294,32,32,392
1435982829132,432,Review?ProductID=1245572,200,OK,jp@gc - Stepping Thread Group 1-4,text,true,294,32,32,432

I understood that 1-1,1-2, 1-3 means threadgroup1 - first thread, Threadgroup1-second thread, But mu doubt is when first thread from first group has already started then why in output it is showinh 1-1,1-1 again and again around 7 to 8 times?? Please help me

Answer (score 0):

What you are showing here is the CSV output of your test.

JMeter shows by default in results the Thread Name, so if you have for example 5 iterations for 1 thread, then you can absolutely have 5 times the Thread-1-1 in the CSV output.

Thread name output is controlled by:

> jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_name=true